# ComponentDidUpdate infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase, react-component

I'm new to React Native and I don't know if you can use componentDidUpdate this way. What I'm trying to do is call getRiderRequestDetails() within componentDidUpdate to retrieve data from Firebase anytime a new request is made. And I get an infinite loop. How can I avoid that?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    getRiderRequestDetails();
   
  }

 getRiderRequestDetails = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("driverId")
      .then((result) =>
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref("Ride_Request/" + result)
          .once("value")
          .then(function (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
              DriverHomeContents.RiderID = snapshot.child("riderID").val();
              DriverHomeContents.RiderPickUpName = snapshot
                .child("pickUpName")
                .val();
              DriverHomeContents.RiderDropUpName = snapshot
                .child("dropOffName")
                .val();
            }
          })
          .then(
            () => {
              console.log(
                "fine " +
                  DriverHomeContents.RiderDropUpName +
                  " " +
                  DriverHomeContents.RiderPickUpName
              );
              if (!DriverHomeContents.RiderID == "") {
                this.setState({ isModalVisible: true });
              }

              firebase
                .database()
                .ref("RiderIds/" + DriverHomeContents.RiderID + "/Details")
                .once("value")
                .then(function (snapshot) {
                  DriverHomeContents.Firstname = snapshot
                    .child("firstname")
                    .val();
                  DriverHomeContents.Lastname = snapshot
                    .child("lastname")
                    .val();
                })
                .then(
                  () => {
                    console.log("fine" + DriverHomeContents.Firstname);
                  },
                  (error) => {
                  }
                );
            },
            (error) => {
              console.error("error" + error);
            }
          )
      )
      .catch((e) => console.log("err", e));
  };
```

Comment: If the component updates, you make a request, which updates the component --- that causes an infinite loop doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now I don't know how to avoid that or where I should call the function instead.

Comment: Why do you need `componentDidUpdate` in the first place? Why not `componentDidMount` ? Then it will fetch the data only once.

Comment: I thought it will make a difference as in it will update the screen without having to refresh it if different requests will be made. I moved the function in componentDidMount and it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

If you read the description on above link, you will see that infinite render is bound to happen because you are updating something and then that causes the lifecycle method to run again and loop happens.

Based on what your requirement is, you can do either of these.

- Check what other lifecycle methods fit your use-case.
- figure out the condition for which you should not make the calls in cDidUpdate. example. checking if `this.props.someProp !== prevProps.someProp` then make your function call.

NOTE: The first param passed to cDidUpdate is `previous props` not previous state.